# ERROR: "Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr." in R-Markdown to PDF

Tags: r, r-markdown, pdflatex, kableextra

I am using a Rmarkdown with KableExtra to create an Invoice table with collapse_rows and pack_rows. Executing this chunk locally generates the wished table layout:

[example table layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mummv.png)

As soon I try to render this markdown with: `rmarkdown::render()`
I receive the following error:

```
output file: billing.knit.md

/usr/bin/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS billing.knit.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output pandoc6d77420b47ac.tex --self-contained --highlight-style tango --latex-engine pdflatex --variable graphics --include-in-header /tmp/RtmpoyiqX9/rmarkdown-str6d777c393955.html
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<recently read> \endtemplate
```

I can only prevent this error by skipping the `collapse_rows` & `pack_rows`.

```
kbl(tot_cost3[,2:ncol(tot_cost3)], format = "latex", booktabs = TRUE, longtable = TRUE, col.names = c("", "analysis type", "samples", "unit price", "sum", "sub total in CHF"), align = "lllcccc") %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("repeat_header")) %>%
  collapse_rows(columns = 6, valign = "bottom", latex_hline = "major", longtable_clean_cut = T) %>%
  pack_rows(index = table(tot_cost$User_name)) %>%
  row_spec(nrow(tot_cost3), bold=TRUE) %>%
  kable_paper(full_width = T)
```

I don't really understand what is going on here, because also a rollback to an earlier, working version of the *.Rmd didn't help. - Still it seems to be somehow related to the **pack_rows** and **collapse_rows** function...

Any hint towards a potential solution is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out what caused the problem:

There was a linebreak **\n** in one of the cells of "tot_cost3" causing the table format to break apart when using pack_rows or collapse_rows!

> LaTeX, somehow shows surprisingly high tolerance on that, which is quite unusual. As a result, it won’t
> throw an error if you are just using kable to make some simple tables. However, when you use kableExtra
> to make some advanced modification, it will start to throw some bugs

from Hao Zhou's "Create Awesome LaTeX Table with knitr::kable and kableExtra" (http://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf) Tutorial provided me with the hint to look for formatting issues in the table content itself...